# Will wireless repeater slow internet speed

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater

When using a wireless repeater, I understand that the `total network bandwidth` will be halved as answered here '[Does a wireless repeater slow things down for everyone?](https://superuser.com/questions/435609/does-a-wireless-repeater-slow-things-down-for-everyone)'

Consider the following arrangement:

**Update:** (changed router1 speed to 150mbps)

- Wireless `Router1` with <s>`300`</s>`150mbps transfer rate`, *connected to* **`1mbps internet`**
- Wifi `repeater` such as [Netgear WN3000RP](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN3000RP.aspx), with 300mbps, repeating `Router1`.

My doubts:

1. What happens to internet speed? Will it be reduced to half i.e. `512kbps`?
2. What happens to network speed? Will it be 300mbps or 150mbps after [Netgear WN3000RP](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN3000RP.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

The internal speed will be halved *only* for whom is connecting to the repeater

For someone connected to `router1` the **internal** speed will be *300mbps*.

For someone connecting to the `repeater` the **internal** speed will be *150mbps*.

Both of them will *enjoy* the *1 Mbps* speed of the **external** link.

Comment: What if `router1` works at 150mbps?

Comment: The average speed for a `repeater` is 50% of the connection to `router`speed. In this case: 75Mbps.