# Trying to expand my 5ghz network coverage trough WDS bridging, but "expanded" router is only receiving half the bandwidth it should

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, speed, wds

So, my root router that receives the ISP fiber link is a Huawei EG8145V5, it receives a 300mbps link and delivers that speed just fine trough the 5ghz band.

The router is placed in my house's office and now i want to have the same link speed coverage in my room, and as many here already know, 5ghz networks don't handle walls very well, so in order to fix that i bought a TP-LINK archer c6 gigabit router and WDS bridged it's 5ghz network to the root router, placing the c6 about 15 ft. away from it, in the house's main hall, with a clean line of sight between the two.

To my surprise, when testing the speed the c6 only gave me 150mbps of download speed instead of 300, despite it having a full signal to the root router and also a full signal to my laptop, resulting in the adapter reporting that i have a 433.33mbps link on it (the maximum bandwidth the adapter support on 5ghz band).

Then i began the troubleshooting, tackled into the c6's channel and channel width configs, turning on stuff like MIMO, disabling the 2.4ghz band, even putting both routers right beside eachother, to no avail, same 150mbps speed every time. As a last resort i decided to connect the routers trough their gigabit ethernet ports, and to my surprise i managed to get the 300mbps download speed on the c6's 5ghz band that way.

So now what i have to ask is:

- Is there a way to fix this so that the WDS bridging alone delivers
  the full 300mbps link speed?
- In case #1 answer is no, can a MESH network solve this issue?

I assume i can be missing some other critical info, so feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a decent answer about speeds being cut in half:

https://superuser.com/questions/435609/does-a-wireless-repeater-slow-things-down-for-everyone

I put a wire (Ethernet) from my network center in the basement to my second floor office and install a Ubiquity Access Point. I get full speed from this.

Comment: Very interesting, but that questions asks about repeaters specifically, in my case its a router -> router situation, and i would like some clarification about if a MESH network would yeld the same problematic results.

Comment: You would need to look at the mesh specifications (there is more than one make). Make sure it specifies that it will maintain speed.

Comment: @john, it's just the one radio problem. Unfortunately alot of the mesh equipment suffers the same problem. Now if you WDS or bridge on 5ghz and rebroadcast on 2.4ghz this is a non issue.